# Fill the blank value in excel as per pervious value

Tags: excel

I have three columns(a,b,c) in excel like below, Now I want to add one more column(d) along with these column and populate the value in the additional column like below.
input file

```
a   b   c
asdf    qw  Y
sdf     
sdf     
asdf        
asdf    2sdf    Y
sadf        
asdf        
sdfa        
asdf    asdfsfd 
asdf        
asdf        
adsf        
asdf    asdfsfd 
asdf        
asdf        
adsf        
asdf    asdfsfd Y
asdf        
asdf        
adsf
```

Output value after adding the column

```
a   b   c   d
asdf    qw  Y   Y
sdf         Y
sdf         Y
asdf            Y
asdf    2sdf    Y   Y
sadf            Y
asdf            Y
sdfa            Y
asdf    asdfsfd     
asdf            
asdf            
adsf            
asdf    asdfsfd     
asdf            
asdf            
adsf            
asdf    asdfsfd Y   Y
asdf            Y
asdf            Y
adsf            Y
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an if statement with a couple of conditions. Is this what you were looking for?

[image]